# A heat equation with the conditions $hu(0,t)- u_{x}(0,t) = 0$ and $u(L,t)+ u_{x}(L,t) = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I must solve the following problem with initial boundary value:

\begin{cases}
u_t = c^2 u_{xx} \hspace{3cm} 0<x<L, \hspace{0.3cm} t>0, \hspace{0.3cm}c>0\\
u(x,0) = f(x) \hspace{2.3cm} 0 \leq x \leq L\\
hu(0,t)- u_{x}(0,t) = 0  \hspace{0,79cm} t \geq 0, \hspace{0.3cm} h>0\\
hu(L,t)+ u_{x}(L,t) = 0  \hspace{0.68cm} t \geq 0, \hspace{0.3cm} h>0
\end{cases}

**My attempt:**

To do this, I proceeded by the method of separation of variables assuming a solution of the form $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$. 
Then, $u_{t} = XT'$ and $u_{xx} = X''T$, so $\frac{T'}{c^{2}T} = \frac{X''}{X} = -\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a constant.

We obtain the ODE  $X'' + \lambda X = 0$
The boundary conditions give:

$$hu(L,t) + u_{x}(L,t) = hX(L)T(t) + X'(L)T(t) = 0 \Rightarrow hX(L) + X'(L) = 0$$
$$hu(0,t) - u_{x}(0,t) = hX(0)T(t) - X'(0)T(t) = 0 \Rightarrow hX(0) - X'(0) = 0$$

We mount the following problem:

\begin{cases}
X'' + \lambda X = 0\\
hX(0)-X'(0) = 0 \hspace{0.65cm} (1)\\
hX(L) + X'(L) = 0 \hspace{0.5cm} (2)
\end{cases}

if $\lambda > 0$, say $\lambda = k^2$ with $k> 0$, then
$$X(x) = a \cos(kx) + b \sin(kx)$$
By equation (1) we have: $ha-kb = 0$
By equation (2) we have: $(ha +kb)\cos(kL) + (hb-ka)\sin(kL) = 0$

As $ha = kb$, then $(2kb)\cos(kL) + (hb-ka)\sin(kL) = 0$

Now my question is: How can I continue with this? Is my reasoning correct? I haven't really found a way to be able to continue with this problem. I need to find $X$ and its coefficients $a$ and $b$. Then get the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ and then find $T$. I appreciate any help you can give me.

Note: I had recently posted this problem, but I have now made a more detailed attempt.

Comment: By equation (1), you have $$ha - \color{red}{k} b = 0$$ You need to check the other condition too. Also, the procedure is not to find $X$ and its coefficients, then the eigenvalues, then $T$. The procedure is to find the general solution for $X$, then determine the eigenvalues $\lambda_{n} = k_{n}^{2}$ and whether one of the coefficients $A_{n}$ _or_ $B_{n}$ vanish or neither vanish, then find the general solution for $T$, then apply the initial condition to get a Fourier series from which you can determine the coefficient $A_{n}$ or  $B_{n}$ or _both_, using the orthogonality relations.

Comment: @mattos Thank you, I have now corrected my results in the conditions. I'm trying to find the eigenvalues.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti  Thank you so much for the correction. Can you give me a suggestion to find the eigenvalues?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti  I think it's a good idea. But does that mean that eigenvalues cannot be explicitly determined? So how can I conclude the problem?